# Lisp plist only in context of symbol's property list cell?

Tags: common-lisp, plist, symbols

Basically, I'm wondering if there is such a thing as a plist in Common Lisp outside the concept of the built-in symbol property list. So if I have

```
(setq Joe '(:fav-season  "Fall" :fav-color  "Blue"))
```

then I do

```
(setf (get 'Joe 'fav-season) "Summer")
(setf (get 'Joe 'fav-color) "Green")
```

I've got two separate plists associated with `Joe` going at once, one ad-hoc, the other "official" because it's bound to the *symbol* `Joe`.

```
(get 'Joe 'fav-color)
"Green"
```

or

```
(symbol-plist 'Joe)
(FAV-COLOR "Green" FAV-SEASON "Summer")
```

So I assume the direct assigning of a plist-like structure to `Joe` (assigning to the symbol `Joes`'s value cell) isn't a truly supported data structure (like `get`, `getf` etc.) as it is with the symbol `Joe`'s property list. Nor as an alist, which is always the value of a variable and has `assoc`, `rassoc`, etc. May I therefore conclude there really is no use of the plist concept in the real world besides the built-in symbol cell for property lists? So often in tutorials, plist is automatically described as the symbol's property list, and there is no further discussion of the concept.

I guess in a backwards way, I'm pursuing the rather vague, spotty idea of what are good, best-practice data structures in Lisp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GETF` to retrieve values from a list, which is a property list.

```
CL-USER 141 > (let ((joe '(:fav-season  "Fall"
                           :fav-color  "Blue")))
                (list (getf joe 'fav-color)
                      (getf joe :fav-color)))
(NIL "Blue")
```

Notice that you need to get the *indicator* right.

You've used `GET`, which can be implemented in terms of `GETF`:

```
(defun get (x y)
  (getf (symbol-plist x) y))
```

Thus one can use property lists not just in symbol property lists - there is a basic operator for it.

Note also that there are many other data structures, which allow access to values via keys: assoc lists, CLOS classes, hash-tables. There are slightly different use cases for those.

Property lists are often used when simple key and value data needs to be used in lists - for example in source code.

Functions use property list like lists for keyword arguments, which one can manipulate:

```
(let ((foo (list 'window :x 100 :y 200)))
   (setf (getf (rest foo) :x) 200)
   (apply #'make-instance foo))
```

Sometimes property lists are added to CLOS classes or structures. Structures in Common Lisp may not be extensible at runtime - they can't be redefined with additional slots. So often some classes and structures have a properties slot, where one can at runtime add/remove/updated the key/value pairs.

Comment: Yes, but to my bigger question, Is a plist only (mainly) for use with a symbol's property list, or is it ever used by itself?

Comment: My confusion came from how tutorials seem to imply that a plist was only employed in the case of symbols. Now I understand that almost the same syntax as with symbol-plists is used when a variable has a plist as a value. Now I have to learn when to use a key/value list, a structure, or an object. Still, it seems strange that we can create a symbol, load it up with a big plist, but if we don't give it an actual value, it's not really any sort of variable, global or lexical. Is that ever done, or have any advantage over normal variable work?

Comment: @147pm historically symbol plists were important internally in Lisp: things like values or functions may have been entries on a plist. Also symbols with plists were probably the earliest objects (in an OOP sense), where the plist entries were the slots&values.

Comment: @147pm still today some Lisp systems have some internal info on a symbol: documentation strings, source location, compiler infos, ...

Answer (score 2):

No, they are used ubiquitously, as a lightweight “map” construct.  For example, in the popular library `alexandria`, there are functions to convert between alists, plists, and hash-tables.  It is rather that the symbol-plists have fallen somewhat out of use.

Comment: This is good to know, especially about the symbol-plist not being used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a symbol as a kind of "object", and not just as the name of a variable, then its plist can be very helpful.  For example, in building a data-structure to represent a partial order (poset), I use symbols as the poset-elements.  A given element x of the poset will have a past, but also a future, etc.  Either or both of these "values" can conveniently be kept on the plist.  The plist can also be used if you want to "mark" an element; this technique is very useful in writing algorithms, e.g. to find the minimal elts of the poset.